# replace URL using shell script

Tags: perl, replace, sed

I am getting below error while I try to replace one url? What is the efficient way to replace URL in all files in a give directory.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 62: unknown option to `s'
```

`find . -name '*' | xargs sed -i 's/old_url/new_url/g'` did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in perl.

```
cd directory
perl -pi -e 's!old_url!new_url!g;' *
```

Comment: Tried that too in command line Can't open perl script "s/http:old_url/http://new_url/": No such file or directory

Comment: Using another delimiter for `s///` would probably be a good idea when using URLs.

Comment: @sharp, You didn't use `-e` if you got that

Comment: @sharp The character following `-i` gets used as the extension of the (optional) backup file. E.g. `-i.bak` creates `file.bak`. So you cannot have additional flags immediately following the `-i` option.

Comment: Any way I can igonore .svn or . getting below erro Can't do inplace edit: ./sharp-files/.svn/text-base is not a regular file.

Answer (score 10):

The fundamental problem is probably that you are specifying something like

```
s/http://example.com/ick/poo/http://example.net/also/not/
```

which is not a valid `sed` or `perl` script, and obviously quite ambiguous.  Use an alternate separator which is not anywhere in either the regular expression or in the replacement; a popular choice is !

```
s!http://example.com/ick/poo!http://example.net/also/not!
```

which is valid in both `sed` and `perl`.

**Edit** Kudos to @TLP for also diagnosing this in a comment.  I'll remove this answer if you post a similar one.

Comment: I'm satisfied with the kudos. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `find` as in your original question:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's{old_url}{new_url}g' {} +
```

And if Perl is telling you "no such file or directory," it's probably because you accidentally omitted the `-e`

EDIT: changed `s///g`s to `s{}{}g` since, as TLP pointed out, you're working with URLs.

EDIT: changed `\;` to `+` per ikegami's suggestion.

Comment: Tip: Change `\;` to `+` to avoid launching so many instances of `perl`. (Requires GNU `find`.)

Comment: @ikegami Excellent tip, +1 and thank you.  I've never heard that after years of UNIX experience and countless `find` commands. (Maybe because I work primarily with Solaris?)

Comment: Nope, just checked the Solaris man page for `find` and there it is, plain as day.  As always, RTFM...